# T-SQL Why can I reffer only once to temporary object?

Tags: t-sql

with tmp_rows as 
    (
        select * from [dbo].[customer]
    )

```
select * from tmp_rows;
select count(*) from tmp_rows;
```

I can't get the count of the tmp_rows because I get the error: **Invalid object name 'tmp_rows'**

If I comment the "select *" query everything is OK

I need to select all rows and then get their count, how to do that ?

Comment: WHy would you need that? The first result contains the number of rows as it contains the rows.

Comment: CTE's aren't really temporary objects in that they get materialised in advance in SQL Server. They are treated pretty much in the same manner as derived tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
with tmp_rows as 
(
    select * from [dbo].[customer]
)

select * from tmp_rows;
select @@rowcount;
```

By declaring you statement in using `with` you are declaring a CTE - further information on CTE's can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)

Comment: Hm, but then the @@rowcount is the global variable, the same for all clients connected to SQL Server ?

Comment: @Tony - if @@ROWCOUNT acted the way you're supposing, what use would it be?

Comment: Actually, with that solution the CTE is totally pointless. You get the same with just `select * from dbo.customer;select @@rowcount`.

Comment: @Guffa - it is true, it is pointless using a CTE but this may be a simple version.

Comment: @Tony - @@ROWCOUNT is [a system function](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187786.aspx) not a global variable. They used to be called global variables but not any more probably to avoid this type of (understandable) confusion.

Answer (score 4):

A temporary object created using the `with` keyword can only be used once. You can create a temporary table if you want to use it more than once:

```
select *
into #tmp_tows
from dbo.customer

select * from #tmp_rows

select count(*) from #tmp_rows

drop table #tmp_rows
```

This works even if you want to do something different with the result twice, for example getting the count before the result.

Answer (score 1):

The CTE starting with WITH ends with the semicolon `;` .

But you can have more than 1 CTE in a WITH statement:

```
with tmp_rows as 
(
    select * from [dbo].customer
),
count_rows as
(
    select COUNT(*) count_rows from tmp_rows
)
select * from count_rows, tmp_rows;
```

Comment: Note: That will include the count in every row in the result instead of as a separate result.

Answer (score 0):

`tmp_rows` is a Common Table Expression (CTE), and CTEs are scoped at the statement level:

```
-- 1st statement, works fine.
with tmp_rows as (select * from [dbo].[customer])
select * from tmp_rows;

-- 2nd statement, returns an error, since tmp_rows is out of scope.
select count(*) from tmp_rows;
```

By the time your second statement executes, `tmp_rows` is already out of scope.

Be aware that CTEs are like locally-scoped **views**, not tables. The result set is never materialized. If you need to materialize a result set, use a local temporary table or table variable instead.